# Is it possible to have a table column which can hold more than one string in asp.net mvc 5 code first approach?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, asp.net-mvc-5

I am very new to ASP.NET MVC 5. I want to have a `Size` column in my `Product` table which can hold more than one string per row. For example, typically attributes hold one value in a data table... for example `'FirstName'`  would hold the single value `John` , `'Address'` would hold the single value `'32 Park Road'` ... But `'Size'` can hold one or more of `'XS' , 'S', 'M' ,'L'  'XL'` .

I have implemented the `Size` column like this in my `Product` model:

```
  public class Product
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public List<Size> Size { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
        public decimal Price { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z\s]{1,255}$",
         ErrorMessage = "Colour is not valid.")]
        public string Colour { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Style { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Description { get; set; }


    }
```

and an Enum for Size:

```
public enum Size
{
    XS,
    S,
    M,
    L,
    XL
}
```

However, after performing `add - migration` and `update database`, I don't see the Size column in my Product table. I will need to retrieve the Size values from each row of the table in my application, but this will not be possible as the column is not in the table.

Comment: You should have a 1-many table for your sizes if there can be multiple Sizes for a Product

Comment: I think you need to make Size a table and manage it through regular relation, otherwise you'll end up violating the first normal form (1NF) in your DB

Comment: Yes I think you are right I will take that approach and make another Size model and then relate it to my Product table.

Comment: What you speak of is a perfect candidate for a lookup table. `Size(Code, Desc)` where `Size` is the primary key and will have one of the values such `SM` and `Desc` will be `Small`. Then you will have one to many from `Product` so you need a table `ProductSize(ProductId, SizeCode)`. Here you can put many products

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comments that you should probably have a separate sizes table but if for some reasons you have a constraint where you can't consider making the Size enum a Flag and then you can store multiple values in one column.

```
[Flags]
public enum Size
{
    None = 0
    XS = 1,
    S = 2,
    M = 4,
    L = 8,
    XL = 16
}
```

and then in your model:

```
[Required]
public Size Size { get; set; }
```